# Convert Keys in Dictionary to All-Capitals

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wish to convert the keys in a dictionary to capitals, but I want the values summed of, for example, "A" and "a":

```
counter = {"A":1,"a":2,b:3}
```

this doesn't quite do it:

```
counter = {l.upper():c for l in counter}
```

What should I be doing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Comment: just do: `{l.upper():c for l, c in counter.items()}` it will leave you with two keys.

Comment: Oh you want to sum the values as well. Then you need to use some `if`s and `+`s, too.

Comment: @YOLO That doesn't combine the two existing values for `A` and `a`, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)

for k, v in counter.items():
    d[k.upper()] += v

d = dict(d)  # optional, if you really want just a regular dict in the end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with `int`, then iterate over your dict, convert the keys, and add the values.

```
from collections import defaultdict

counter = {"A": 1, "a": 2, 'b': 3}
d = defaultdict(int)

for k, v in counter.items():
    k = k.upper()
    d[k] += v

print(dict(d))  # -> {'A': 3, 'B': 3}
```